# Update form Cakephp 3

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently working on a project using cakephp 3.

I have a form to add clients which works using this in my controller :

```
    public function add(){

        $clients = $this->Clients->newEntity();
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $clients = $this->Clients->patchEntity($clients, $this->request->data);
            if($this->Clients->save($clients)){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Client has been created.'));
                return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Clients','action'=>'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Client hasnt been created.'));
        }
        $this->set('clients',$clients);

    }
```

Then I want to have the possibility to modify one of my client.
I have a table of clients and when I click on of them, I have a modify button coming (jQuery).
Then I'm on my modify page. I did some test with the doc from cake but it seems I don't understand how it works and what tools should I use.

For the moment, I have this on my Controller:

```
public function modify($id = null){
            if(empty($id)){
                throw new NotFoundException;
            }
            $clients = $this->Clients->get($id);
            /* there should be the modify code */
            $this->set('clients', $clients);

        }
```

I don't really know what to use as I said...  Any help pls?

Comment: try with updateAll by providing id.

Comment: thanks for your answer @anantkumarsingh . I am looking updateAll() and I dont get what I should put it in the $fields and $conditions. The SQL request I want is UPDATE clients SET (all the fields in the form) WHERE id = $id...

Comment: Please try and tell me is it working or not?

Comment: I edited my answer, I guess it could work with updateAll, but the doc from cake is a bit informationless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for editing a record is quite straight forward:

```
public function modify($id = null){
        if(empty($id)){
            throw new NotFoundException;
        }
        $client = $this->Clients->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put']) {
            $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {
                return $this->redirect($someURL);
            }
        }
        $this->set('client', $client);

}
```

Comment: thanks @JoséLorenzo , it works ! updateAll isnt usefull in this situation I guess !

Comment: More on patching entities (only updating fields that have changed) can be found in the docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities